# AngularJS function not returning desired value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

I have a function to determine if a header is supposed to be shown on a page or not. The angular controller is as follows:

```
angular.module('blahblah').controller('blahblahController', [
    '$location',
    function blahblahController($location) {
        'use strict';

        this.shouldShow = function () {
            return $location.url() !== '/homepage';
        };
    }
]);
```

Like this the function will evaluate to true in every page except the homepage, so the `ng-if="$ctrl.shouldShow()"` will show the element on the page.

My problem is that I'd like the function to evaluate to true in every page except the homepage and the `'/error'` page.

I've tried to replace `'/homepage'` with `'/homepage' || '/error'`, and also putting it between parenthesis but it doesn't work.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try contains instead of !== and check UpCase and/or LoCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.shouldShow = function () {
 return !($location.url() === '/homepage' || $location.url() === '/error');
};
```

Check if the url is either equal to homepage or error and negate it. This will return true for all pages except homepage and error page.

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's my first post!

Answer (score -1):

You need two comparisons:

```
this.shouldShow = function () {
   let path = $location.path();
   return path !== '/homepage' || path !== '/error';
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Angular controllers need $scope injected so that any properties are attached to the $scope object. In the controller any properties you would like available to in the template would need to to be prefixed by $scope.
For example

```
$scope.shouldShow = function () {
        return $location.url() !== '/homepage';
};
```

In your template your would use: `ng-if=shouldShow()`

See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller for more info.

You are using `ng-if="$ctrl.shouldShow()"` in your template. AngularJS components default controllerAs uses $ctrl.  See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component for more info.

Comment: You don't need `$scope` when using `controllerAs` alias which would be why OP is using `this` to assign properties to the controller object

Comment: Very true, but the post did not include that information so I did not want to assume he was using `ng-contoller: "blahblahController as $ctrl"`.  With only the information given the `ng-if` statement would never evaluate to true.